# GitLab CI failing due to gem load error

Tags: ruby, git, rubygems, continuous-integration, gitlab

I have a ruby script that fails the GitLab CI build with:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- git (LoadError)
```

The ruby script:

```
require 'git'
```

Here's the .gitlab-ci.yml file:

```
image: gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest

job1:
  script:
    - apt-get update && apt-get -y install ruby && apt-get install git
    - gem install git
    - ./script.rb
```

I've also tried adding a gemfile with the git gem and running:

```
image: gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest

job1:
  script:
    - apt-get update && apt-get -y install ruby && apt-get install git
    - gem install bundler
    - bundle install
    - ./script.rb
```

But I get the same error

Answer (score 0):

So it was quite simple.

Needed to sudo the gem install:

```
image: gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest

job1:
  script:
    - apt-get update && apt-get -y install ruby && apt-get install git
    - sudo gem install git
    - ./script.rb
```